# Form variable does not refresh with ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm building a simple email sending form and wanted to make it with ajax. The form submits correctly the first time but if you make any subsequent changes to the text in the form and then submit again then jquery does not pick up on the changes and posts the old data. Whats going on?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();

$j(document).ready(function() {
    var submit_url = "mail_submit.php";
    var send_email = $j("#sendemail");

    send_email.click(function() {
        var form = $j("#post");

        $j.post(submit_url, form.serialize(), function(data) {
            alert(data);
        });

    });
});
```

Comment: Does it occur in all browsers such as IE, FireFox, Chrome, Safari, etc.?

Comment: This question has been resolved. I went a different route with this page and the problem went away. I think it had something to do with the tinymce editor.

Comment: Bingo! I have also had issues with TinyMCE and jQuery form submission. If my memory is correct, there is a hidden text area that you need to manually populate if you're submitting the form via jQuery.

Comment: Yes I updated the question with my answer below. This question was resolved but I ran into almost exactly the same thing again. tinyMCE.triggerSave() is what you need to call to save the tinymce data to the hidden form field that you can then read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran into this problem again.

To solve it you need to use tinyMCE.triggerSave();
The method is outlined here http://maestric.com/doc/javascript/tinymce_jquery_ajax_form

My final code is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();

$j(document).ready(function() {
    var submit_url = "mail_submit.php?action=";
    var actions = $j("#sendEmail, a#previewEmail, a#saveEmail, a#updateEmail");
    var loading = $j("img#ajax-loading");
    var status = $j("span#post-status-display");

    actions.click(function() {
        tinyMCE.triggerSave();
        var form = $j("#post");
        var action = $j(this).attr("id");
        var update_div = $j("#update-div");
        loading.show();

        $j.post(submit_url + action, form.serialize(), function(data){
            update_div.html(data);
            update_div.fadeIn();
            loading.hide();
        });

    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

It's working just [fine](http://jsfiddle.net/ifaour/DtBkE/).
Now I would prefer calling the `submit` event on the form itself, but if you are using a `submit` input type, remember to `return false;`

Comment: The code itself is correct. I think the issue was some sort of javascript conflict with the tinymce editor. If i disabled that and just used a blank textbox then all is well.

Comment: @ChrisOPeterson: so you solved it or not yet? please update your question with the new inputs!